# Projection of the top of a cone

Tags: r, geometry

Knowing the coordinates of points A (xA, yA, Za) and B (xB, yB, zB), is it possible to obtain the coordinates of point C (xC, yC, zC)?

[image]

**Edit:**

As Gregor Thomas explains, this does not seem possible. Now if I have a point D which is the projection of B through A of the same length. Can I have its projection E so that I can calculate the midpoint of the segment EB to know C?

[image]

Comment: (0, Ya, Za) ???

Comment: `C` is not uniquely defined by `A` and `B`. You can imagine holding your cone by `A` and `B` and rotating it around the `AB` line, moving `C` through many possibilities. You'll need to make more assumptions to uniquely define `C`. If you assume that `xC` is 0 and `AC` is normal to the `x = 0` plane, then Yves' answer is correct.

Comment: I think knowledge of the vertex of the cone and any two points on the base would be one combination that would enable C to be identified.  And I think we are all assuming a right circular cone rather than an oblique cone, right?

Comment: Yes, it's a right circular cone, I should have mentioned that.

Comment: The assumptions that are not explicitly stated in the text but implied by the diagram are that the line CB is parallel to the z axis, and AC is parallel to the x axis. This also implies that the base is parallel to the zy plane. If these assumptions are allowed, then C is given by [Bx, Ay, Az]. Working out the point D will not help unless these assumptions are also met, since the cone can be rotated around the BD line just as easily as it can around the AB line.